# Android - Add subview after animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I'm trying to add a subview below another view after an animation. anyone have any idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
this.animate().translationY(newY - 170).setDuration(500).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            clearAnimation();

            RouteBreakDownLayout routeBreakDownLayout = new RouteBreakDownLayout(mContext);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.selected_route_layout);
            routeBreakDownLayout.setLayoutParams(p);
            addView(routeBreakDownLayout);

        }
    }).start();
```

Here is the XML for the layout. I have a scrollview embeded which will hold the content that needs to be animated in.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/selected_route_layout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/selected_route_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="10dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#1D1C18" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eta_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/time_label"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/time_label"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time_label"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#7EC82F" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/route_breakdown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/time_label"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/via_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/route_breakdown"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#BDBDBD" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/arrow_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:src="@drawable/transit_symbol_up_arrow" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/selected_route_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp" />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What goes wrong for you in your code-snippet?

Here's working example I came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/containerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/detailsView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#FF0000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And MainActivity is

```
package klogi.com.animationstestapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final View detailsView = findViewById(R.id.detailsView);
        final View headerView = findViewById(R.id.headerView);
        final RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.containerRelativeLayout);
        container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                detailsView.animate().translationY(-detailsView.getY()).setDuration(500).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Button additionalButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                        additionalButton.setText("Additional button");

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams additionalButtonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        additionalButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                        additionalButton.setLayoutParams(additionalButtonParams);

                        container.addView(additionalButton);
                    }
                }).start();

                headerView.animate().translationY(detailsView.getHeight()).setDuration(500).start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It works just as expected.

Have you tried to add your control(RouteBreakDownLayout) **without** animation? Does it work? It can be something like control is actually adding, but it's out of the viewport, etc. - so far, I can just guessing.

Comment: I changed the layout to a linearlayout but it still doesn't add the RouteBreakDownLayout. If I draw the parent layout at the top,            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" and just draw the RouteBreakDown with animation it works fine, but I need the routebreakdown to appear once the animation is complete.

Comment: @Mikerizzo 1) Correct me, if I'm wrong: you're trying to draw the new item below the item, which is set as android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"? It'd be easier to understand, if you post your XML here also.    2) Try to run just the same code, as you wrote in run() method without animations. Does it work?

Comment: Yup you are correct but I want to draw the new item when the animation is finished. I've added the xml to the original question.

Comment: @Mikerizzo The thing is to make it works without animations first, and then make it works with animation. Can you double-check that it works without animation?   And you **can't** add item "below" the one, which is android:layout_alignParentBottom="true". As the one is already on the bottom. So your item might be in the ViewHierarchy of your app, but out of the viewport

Comment: btw, you can check you view hierarchy in Hierarchy Viewer (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) to make sure, that the widget has been added. It'd give you clearer picture of what is going wrong.

Comment: How can I solve this problem? So be able to animate something that starts at the bottom and move it to the top then show additional content?

Comment: @Mikerizzo I slightly updated my answer above. Now we have a TextView (headerTextView) and it located on the bottom of the screen in RelativeLayout. Once you click somewhere, headerTextView moves straight on the top of the screen and after animation completed - new button( additionalButton ) has been added. I'm placing additionalButton on the bottom of the screen, but you can variate it as you wish by applying new rules (like I did with RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM; NB! applying below the element which is pre-specified as the bottom one won't work.).   Hope it helps.

Comment: it kinda works but it puts the view ontop and hides the parent view. Dont i need to add layout_below?

Comment: @Mikerizzo it's kind of expected. If you want to avoid overlapping, you need to animate other parts of UI then. I updated the answer, now it's green and red rectangles. Once animation starts - red one moves on top, green one moves below red one and in the end - new button shows up.

Comment: Animations & complicated ViewGroups like RelativeLayouts or LinearLayouts drive many people crazy :-) As once you start animating them, it's really confusing to see, if the position of the widget inside influenced by the rules from the ViewGroup or it's been moved via translations. I'd say, FrameLayout suits animations better (imho)

Comment: You're absolutely right. I got it working though. Just had to macgyver what you posted above.